# Why is my Vue 3 watch callback not firing for a ref variable in useMenu.ts but works in AppLayout.vue in my Electron-Vue3 project?

Tags: electron, vuejs3, watch

vue3 watch is not work

I tried to watch a ref variable in my electron vue3 project, and the watch callback didn't fire in usemenu.ts, but it did fire in AppLayout.vue, I think maybe I called useMenu in the electron's environment, But I need the BrowserWindow variable on the electron environment to do something. What do I do

This is where I created the variable config that requires watch

```
const config = ref<Config>(defaultConfig)
```

export function useConfig() {
config.value = readConfig()

```
function isConfigExist(): boolean {
    const exist = fs.existsSync(process.env.CONFIG_PATH)
    if (!exist) {
        return false
    } else {
        try {
            const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(process.env.CONFIG_PATH))
            const defaultConfigKeys = Object.keys(defaultConfig)
            const configKeys = Object.keys(config)
            return defaultConfigKeys.every((key) => configKeys.includes(key))
        } catch (e) {
            return false
        }
    }
}

function createDefaultConfig(): void {
    fs.existsSync(join(process.env.CONFIG_PATH, '..')) || fs.mkdirSync(join(process.env.CONFIG_PATH, '..'))
    fs.writeFileSync(process.env.CONFIG_PATH, JSON.stringify(defaultConfig))
    config.value = readConfig()
}

function readConfig(): Config {
    if (!isConfigExist()) {
        createDefaultConfig()
    }
    return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(process.env.CONFIG_PATH))
}

watch(config, () => {
    console.log('useConfig config changed')
    fs.writeFileSync(process.env.CONFIG_PATH, JSON.stringify(config.value))
}, {
    deep: true
})

if (!isConfigExist()) {
    createDefaultConfig()
}

return {config, createDefaultConfig, readConfig}
```

}

i try to watch it in AppLayout.vue, it is work

```
import {useConfig} from "../hook/useConfig";
import {watch} from "vue";

const {config} = useConfig()

watch(config, () => {
    console.log('AppLout config changed')
}, {
    deep: true
})
```

I then called the useMenu Create menu when I created the window on electron

```
async function createWindow() {
win = new BrowserWindow({
    title: 'Main window',
    icon: join(process.env.PUBLIC, 'favicon.ico'),
    webPreferences: {
        // Warning: Enable nodeIntegration and disable contextIsolation is not secure in production
        // Consider using contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld
        // Read more on https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false,
        preload
    },
    width: 1440,
    height: 840,
    minWidth: 1440,
    minHeight: 840,
    // frame: false,
})

if (process.env.VITE_DEV_SERVER_URL) { // electron-vite-vue#298
    await win.loadURL(url)
} else {
    await win.loadFile(indexHtml)
}

// Make all links open with the browser, not with the application
win.webContents.setWindowOpenHandler(({url}) => {
    if (url.startsWith('https:')) shell.openExternal(url)
    return {action: 'deny'}
})

useMenu(win)
```

}

I tried to get config in useMenu the same way I did in AppLayout and watch it, but it didn't work

```
export function useMenu(win) {
const {config} = useConfig()
const menu = computed(() => {
    return Menu.buildFromTemplate([
        {
            label: '开发快捷键',
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: '切换开发者工具',
                    accelerator: 'F12',
                    click: () => {
                        win.webContents.toggleDevTools()
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: '刷新',
                    accelerator: 'Ctrl+R',
                    click: () => {
                        win.reload()
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            label: '播放快捷键',
            submenu: [
                {
                    label: '播放/暂停',
                    accelerator: config.value.hotkeyConfig.hotkeys.play.key,
                    click: () => {
                        console.log('播放/暂停')
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: '下一首',
                    accelerator: config.value.hotkeyConfig.hotkeys.next.key,
                    click: () => {
                        console.log('下一首')
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: '上一首',
                    accelerator: config.value.hotkeyConfig.hotkeys.previous.key,
                    click: () => {
                        console.log('上一首')
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: '音量+',
                    accelerator: config.value.hotkeyConfig.hotkeys.volumeUp.key,
                    click: () => {
                        console.log('音量+')
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: '音量-',
                    accelerator: config.value.hotkeyConfig.hotkeys.volumeDown.key,
                    click: () => {
                        console.log('音量-')
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: '显示/隐藏窗口',
                    accelerator: config.value.hotkeyConfig.hotkeys.windowShow.key,
                    click: () => {
                        console.log('显示/隐藏窗口')
                    }
                },
                {
                    label: '退出',
                    accelerator: config.value.hotkeyConfig.hotkeys.quit.key,
                    click: () => {
                        console.log('退出')
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ])
})

watch(config, () => {
    console.log('useMenu config changed')
}, {
    deep: true
})

Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu.value)
```

}

Comment: Please post your code as text instead of images

Comment: Your post is simply impossible to read because of the images and your background. The best practice when asking questions here is to copy your actual code and format it nicely so it can easily be read and even tested by the community members. I would suggest editing your post.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by defining a function in useConfig to go to watch config in useConfig

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).